# How can I get poppler to use the extra encoding data in a non-standard directory?

Tags: poppler, pdftotext

I'm testing pdftotext as a part of [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org). It came pre-installed on the shared host that I'm using. I'd like to add the poppler encoding data which contain language packs to help combat errors such as `"Missing language pack for 'Adobe-GB1' mapping"`.

Since it doesn't appear that I have permission to install the encoding data in the recommended directory on my shared host (`/usr/share/poppler`), how can I tell poppler where I've placed the data so that it will get used?

The [pdftotext man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext) doesn't appear to describe any flags that would point to the data packages.

pdftotext resides at `/usr/bin/pdftotext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that seems not to be possible.

Assuming that your hoster uses Linux, the file relevant to reading the encoding data is [GlobalParams](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/tree/poppler/GlobalParams.cc). [Lines 170](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/tree/poppler/GlobalParams.cc#n170) and [677](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/tree/poppler/GlobalParams.cc#n677) deal with initializing the base data directory and the paths for encodings, and these use **compile-time hard-coded values** for the base directory. There is no facility to pass arguments to `poppler` (and, as a consequence, to any package depending on it), and there also is no user-writable configuration file like for many other Linux software packages to change that behavior.

Your best chance is to ask your hosting provider to install these features for you. Many smaller providers will react friendly towards such a request. Otherwise, you'll have to change your provider.

Comment: Thank you for that thoroughly researched answer! I really appreciate it. So then as an alternative do you think I could install my own version of poppler in the directories that I have full access to? Then I could install the additional data packages along with it and just make sure I use that poppler instead of the one in the system path.

Comment: With shell access, this is certainly possible, though I wouldn't underestimate the complexity. You'd have to compile your version, ideally on that host (which requires access to a compiler), and you'd have to get the dependencies right. In the course of that, you would set the data packages directory to something that you have a access to. However, if you're not really good with Linux, I'd try to convince the hoster for quite a while before going down that route. Thanks!